# Vba Excel How to edit cell values in particular columns without looping all Rows based on Cell Contents?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a SpreadSheet with data like shown. I want to hide the value of the cell in last column of a row if the corresponding **SOA** column in the same row has a value of **1A**. I have some thousands of rows so i don't want to loop through all rows. Is there any alternative instead of looping through all rows? Any help would be appreciated greatly.

---

[image]

Comment: So do you want to hide the last column if any of the rows in the SOA column is 1A?  Also do you want to avoid loop through the rows since you think it's too slow to handle the thousands of rows?  If that is the case you can set the range to a variable and loop through the variable as this is quite quick.

Comment: hide or set that particular cell value with an empty string. And now i am doing in the same way as you told but i want to avoid the looping :-(

Comment: Ok, so I need you to clarify your current loop is looping through the cells in the range and not through a variable (ie `vData = Range("A1:E10").value).  I tried with a range of 200,000 rows and it took 1 second for me.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need VBA for this. Insert the following formula into cell F2 and fill down:

`=IF(C2="1A","",E2)`

You could also do this using `Format as Table`, filtering `SOA` by the value `1A` and then deleting the contents of the `Exclusive` row.

Finally, if you must use VBA, use program logic like the following pseudo-code:

```
For each cell in SOA
  If cell.value = "1A"
  Range("E" & cell.Row).Value = ""
Next cell
```